# oracle has 'DESCRIBE' to get all the details of the table like wise does t/sql has any thing

Tags: t-sql

oracle has 'DESCRIBE' to get all the details of the table like wise does t/sql has any thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has `sp_help`/`sp_helptext`

MySQL has `describe`

Answer (score 1):

Sql-Server's sp_help is about as close as you get for something built-in.  Remeber to put the tablename in as a parameter...:-)

```
EXEC sp_help 'mytable'
```

If you're in ssms, you can r-click your query window and opt to output results to text -- it's a little easier to read the output.

ms-help://MS.SQLCC.v10/MS.SQLSVR.v10.en/s10de_6tsql/html/913cd5d4-39a3-4a4b-a926-75ed32878884.htm

Also -- you can write your own using the system tables (sys.objects, sys.columns, ...)  I think 'DESCRIBE' just gives you column name, nullable, and type...  so not nearly as much as sp_help provides.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE parent_obj = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'table_name') AND xtype='PK'
```

will show table details.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.Tables
```

will list all tables

There is no describe equivalent. 
you might find this searching for MSSQL instead of T/SQL.  Most people talking about Transact SQL are talking about stored procedures.